# Python cv2 displays low quality image

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, opencv

I made a Python script that keeps checking a directory for .png´s. If there is a png, it displays the png in a newly created window and deletes the png afterwards. I'm on Windows 11 and I use Python 3.11.3.

The only problem is that the Python script shows the image with low quality. The image itself is of high quality. How can I change my code so the png´s are shown with high resolution?

This is the code:

```
import os
import cv2

desktop_path = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop")  # Get the path to the Desktop

while True:
    # List all files in the Desktop directory
    files = os.listdir(desktop_path)

    for file in files:
        if file.lower().endswith('.png'):  # Check if the file is a PNG image
            file_path = os.path.join(desktop_path, file)

            # Read the image using OpenCV
            image = cv2.imread(file_path)

            # Check if the image was successfully loaded
            if image is not None:
                # Resize the image to a smaller size
                resized_image = cv2.resize(image, (800, 600))

                # Create a new window and display the resized image
                cv2.imshow('PNG Viewer', resized_image)
                cv2.waitKey(2000)  # Wait for 1 second

                # Delete the PNG file
                os.remove(file_path)

    # Delay for a few seconds before checking again
    cv2.waitKey(2000)
```

Comment: Are all the originals the same size? What size?

Comment: @MarkSetchell The newly created window is not the same size as the png because then it will fill up the whole screen.

Comment: Try calling `cv2.resizeWindow('PNG Viewer', 800, 600)` after your `ìmshow` call and remove `resized_image = cv2.resize(image, (800, 600))`

Comment: OpenCV is not a GUI toolkit. please use a GUI toolkit. -- ***show*** us what you see. we can't see what you see.

Comment: @FlyingTeller that won't change things. the window wasn't created to be resizable. it's "auto-size", i.e. shows the data scaled 1:1.

Answer (score 1):

Change this one line which changes the size/resolution of the image. 1280 pixels is the width and 720 pixels is the height now. You can change the numbers to a higher value for a bigger size.

```
resized_image = cv2.resize(image, (1280, 720))
```

Or you can remove the resize entirely so that it will always show at the original size.

```
import os
import cv2

    desktop_path = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop")  # Get the path to the Desktop
    
    while True:
        # List all files in the Desktop directory
        files = os.listdir(desktop_path)
    
        for file in files:
            if file.lower().endswith('.png'):  # Check if the file is a PNG image
                file_path = os.path.join(desktop_path, file)
    
                # Read the image using OpenCV
                image = cv2.imread(file_path)
    
                # Check if the image was successfully loaded
                if image is not None:
                    
                    # Show the image without resize
                    cv2.imshow('PNG Viewer', image)
                    cv2.waitKey(2000)  # Wait for 1 second
    
                    # Delete the PNG file
                    os.remove(file_path)
    
        # Delay for a few seconds before checking again
        cv2.waitKey(2000)
```

Comment: The quality is better but it fills too much of my screen. I don't want the window to be that big. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `cv.resize()` with an `INTER_*` flag.

The default is nearest neighbor sampling.

Try `INTER_AREA` instead.

```
resized_image = cv2.resize(image, (800, 600), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

Also: please use a GUI toolkit. OpenCV is for computer vision, not for displaying pictures. It's not good at GUIs. It's good at computer vision.

Comment: It looks better, but it's still blurry.

Comment: show us what you see.